# WP query is calling get_userdata and throws error

Tags: wp-query

My function is:

```
function wp_query_get_products() {
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1000,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ) );
    if($query->have_posts()) :
        while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            echo get_the_ID();
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
```

Calling this function throws this error

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_userdata() in XXXX.php
> on line 4489

I've written a plugin where I need to get woocommerce products using WP Query, where this part is throwing error. Please suggest what might be causing this.

Thanks

Comment: Where is this code being called?

Comment: I created a plugin where I've added this code, the function is intended to do something else I did echo id to make sure that the error is coming up at WP Query. Calling this function anywhere throws this error.

Comment: Where are you actually running `wp_query_get_products()` though?

Comment: This is called on `register_activation_hook`.

Comment: what is the XXXX.php? There's not enough information or code here to answer this, we need to know how and where it's used. Use the edit link to put this information in the question rather than keeping it hidden in the comments. Also you shouldn't be outputting things in `register_activation_hook`, it's inappropriate. What are you trying to do that requires this code? What were you trying to build?

Comment: to be clear, there is nothing in the code you shared that would cause this error, there is more to this than you've told us

Comment: XXXX.php is filename, and I'm not outputting here, it's just to test, I'm writing product data to .txt file on plugin activation. This is strange as it works on some hosts and throws error on some.

Comment: Without showing the actual code that is throwing the error, no one here can help you.

Comment: This part of snippet was throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call that code from within a [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/). Calling it directly inside your plugin is way too soon - `get_userdata` is a *pluggable* function and will not yet be loaded.

Comment: I'm calling at `register_activation_hook`, tested at `init` too and got same error.